# How the servers know i am using VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

Like steam,if i am connecting through VPN then i will be blocked to make any payment.But how do they detect that?Scan the network adapter on my PC?
I've tried googled this problem but seems like not many discussion it out there.

Comment: most likely steam is knows the IP you are connecting through is a vpn endpoint, and is checking a blocklist before allowing certain operations. that's actually kind of enlightened. I would have just dropped your packets if I wanted to block obfuscated sources. also, make sure your VPN is not configured for split tunneling, as that may give info about your actual location to the local steam client.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mechanisms that Steam *might* use to identify a particular computer -- Google 'browser fingerprinting' for examples -- but in the case of a VPN, the easiest way to know is probably to check the IP address it sees when you connect.

When you use a VPN, the IP address that your ISP assigns to your machine is hidden, and the IP address of the VPN provider is used instead.  Steam is very likely warning you that the account you are logged in under has never done so from that IP address before.

Stema should send you an email with a magic number to enter, which will 'confirm' that the IP address you are using to access Steam is really you.  Once you enter the number into Steam it should prevent that warning from coming up again.

Of course, the VPN provider might choose to refresh your IP address from time to time, so you may find you have to repeat the process, every now and again.

Comment: Thanks for replying.But that still can not clear the confusion.I came up with the idea that maybe they collected the ip addresses of the VPN servers from time to time,like some website or google's "traffic monitoring from the same IP" technique.